# Expand Pandas Dataframes adding rows by different ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, expand

I have a dataframe like this:

| SEG | FAM | GAMA | MIN_RAT | MAX_RAT | VALOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1 | 2 | 5,15 |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,1 | 3 | 2,55 |

And I need to "expand" the df adding new rows to make a new dataframe like this:

| SEG | FAM | GAMA | MIN_RAT | MAX_RAT | VALOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1 | 1 | **10,30** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,1 | 1,1 | **9,79** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,2 | 1,2 | **9,27** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,3 | 1,3 | **8,76** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,4 | 1,4 | **8,24** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,5 | 1,5 | **7,73** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,6 | 1,6 | **7,21** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,7 | 1,7 | **6,70** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,8 | 1,8 | **6,18** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,9 | 1,9 | **5,67** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2 | 2 | **5,15** |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,1 | 2,1 | **5,10** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,2 | 2,2 | **4,82** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,3 | 2,3 | **4,53** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,4 | 2,4 | **4,25** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,5 | 2,5 | **3,97** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,6 | 2,6 | **3,68** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,7 | 2,7 | **3,40** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,8 | 2,8 | **3,12** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2,9 | 2,9 | **2,83** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 3 | 3 | **2,55** |

The values ​​of the column "VALOR" are constructed dividing :

- 5.15 of the original table by the number of new rows between MIN_RAT=1 and MAX_RAT = 2 and adding that value to 5.15 (in this case we add 0.515 in each row)
- 2,55 of the original table by the number of new rows between MIN_RAT=2,1 and MAX_RAT = 3 and adding that value to 2.55 (in this case we add 0.28 in each row)

Is it possible to do this optimally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
rnglist=[np.arange(i, j+.1, 0.1) for i, j in list(zip(df['MIN_RAT'], df['MAX_RAT']))]

dfm = df.reindex(df.index.repeat([len(x) for x in rnglist]))

dfm['MIN_RAT'] = np.concatenate(rnglist)
dfm['MAX_RAT'] = np.concatenate(rnglist)

dfm['VALOR']=  dfm.groupby(level=0)['VALOR']\
                  .transform(lambda x: ((x.notna().cumsum()-1)/(x.count()-1)*x.iloc[0])[::-1]+x.iloc[0])
print(dfm)
```

Output:

```
   EG  FAM  GAMA  MIN_RAT  MAX_RAT      VALOR
0  PE    1     2      1.0      1.0  10.300000
0  PE    1     2      1.1      1.1   9.785000
0  PE    1     2      1.2      1.2   9.270000
0  PE    1     2      1.3      1.3   8.755000
0  PE    1     2      1.4      1.4   8.240000
0  PE    1     2      1.5      1.5   7.725000
0  PE    1     2      1.6      1.6   7.210000
0  PE    1     2      1.7      1.7   6.695000
0  PE    1     2      1.8      1.8   6.180000
0  PE    1     2      1.9      1.9   5.665000
0  PE    1     2      2.0      2.0   5.150000
1  PE    1     2      2.1      2.1   5.100000
1  PE    1     2      2.2      2.2   4.816667
1  PE    1     2      2.3      2.3   4.533333
1  PE    1     2      2.4      2.4   4.250000
1  PE    1     2      2.5      2.5   3.966667
1  PE    1     2      2.6      2.6   3.683333
1  PE    1     2      2.7      2.7   3.400000
1  PE    1     2      2.8      2.8   3.116667
1  PE    1     2      2.9      2.9   2.833333
1  PE    1     2      3.0      3.0   2.550000
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the initial dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['PE', 1,2,1,2,5.15], ['PE', 1,2,2.1,3,2.55]],
                  columns=['SEG', 'FAM', 'GAMA', 'MIN_RAT', 'MAX_RAT', 'VALOR'])
```

You can do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def extrapolate(s):
    start = s['MIN_RAT']
    stop  = s['MAX_RAT']
    value = s['VALOR']
    n = int((stop-start)/0.1)+1
    d = pd.concat([s for i in range(n)], axis=1).T
    d['MIN_RAT'] = np.linspace(start, stop, n)
    d['MAX_RAT'] = df['MIN_RAT']
    d['VALOR']   = np.linspace(2*value, value, n)
    return d

pd.concat([extrapolate(s) for _,s in df.iterrows()])
```

output:

```
  SEG FAM GAMA  MIN_RAT  MAX_RAT     VALOR
0  PE   1    2   1.0000   1.0000  10.30000
0  PE   1    2   1.1000   1.1000   9.78500
0  PE   1    2   1.2000   1.2000   9.27000
0  PE   1    2   1.3000   1.3000   8.75500
0  PE   1    2   1.4000   1.4000   8.24000
0  PE   1    2   1.5000   1.5000   7.72500
0  PE   1    2   1.6000   1.6000   7.21000
0  PE   1    2   1.7000   1.7000   6.69500
0  PE   1    2   1.8000   1.8000   6.18000
0  PE   1    2   1.9000   1.9000   5.66500
0  PE   1    2   2.0000   2.0000   5.15000
1  PE   1    2   2.1000   2.1000   5.10000
1  PE   1    2   2.2125   2.2125   4.78125
1  PE   1    2   2.3250   2.3250   4.46250
1  PE   1    2   2.4375   2.4375   4.14375
1  PE   1    2   2.5500   2.5500   3.82500
1  PE   1    2   2.6625   2.6625   3.50625
1  PE   1    2   2.7750   2.7750   3.18750
1  PE   1    2   2.8875   2.8875   2.86875
1  PE   1    2   3.0000   3.0000   2.55000
```

Comment: you can add `.reset_index(drop=True)` to the last command to have unique indices